# Forces supporting a beam

Tags: beam, kinematics

[image]

I've been struggling with this engineering problem. The forces I've got are Frb=2.08kN, Fray=15.12kN, and Frax=3kN. Before i give in my calculations I need to do a check if they are correct or not with an error up to 0.5%. The problem is the way of checking given by my professor is very consufing and I keep getting error that is higher than 0.5%. Maybe you can spot a mistake I did when calculating or atleas confirm that my forces are correct and the problem is figuring out how to do the checking of my calculations.I attached a png of my scheme.
P.S hope you can see the png

Answer (score 1):

The sketch below is an equivalent system of the original problem. Now try solving for the reactions.

[image]